# making div tags take up full length of the page

Tags: html, css, height

If I have the following code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .left {
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: green;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .right {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">Text</div>
        <div class="right">Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

, how would I go about making each of the div tags take up the full height of the page/viewport (so that the green and red colours extend all the way down to the page even if there is little content within the divs)?

Comment: Oh, internet is full of solutions. There's a huge thread (scroll down to check the latest ones) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 ways to do this:
first:
either give each div right/left 100% height
but you have to set the container/html/body elements height to 100% as well because the right and left divs will inherit the height of parents.

2nd way:
set the height of right/left divisions to 100vh;

example:

```
.right{
height:100vh
}
.left{
height:100vh
}
```

also, check it here .. to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/qkxhyobt/

Answer (score 0):

You just change your style attribute `height:100%` to `height:100vh`. Then It work perfectly.